# How to create or invoke protected constructor of abstract class using reflection?

Tags: c#

I am trying to invoke or create instance of abstract class using reflection. Is this possible. This is what I tried, but I get an error saying "Cannot create an instance of abstract class".

```
Type dynType = myTypes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "MyAbstractClass");
ConstructorInfo getCons = 
dynType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null);
object dynamicInstance = getCons.Invoke(null);
```

**EDIT:** Can I access properties of this abstract class using reflection?

Comment: It is not possible to instantiate an abstract class

Comment: @Downvoters: I think this question is not so bad to downvote it. Yes, answer for this question is simple, but it still can be valuable to others.

Comment: @Virus: "Can I access properties of this abstract class using reflection"? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the constructor on an abstract class is equivalent to trying to instantiate an abstract class, which is not possible (you can not create instances of abstract classes).

What you need to do is create an instance of a derived class and declare its constructor so that it calls the base constructor as in:

```
public class DerivedClass : AbstractClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Complete example:

```
public abstract class Abstract
{
    public Abstract()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract");
    }
}

public class Derived : Abstract
{
    public Derived() : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
    }
}
```

The output of this is

```
Abstract
Derived
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class, not even using reflection.

If you need an instance, either:

- remove the `abstract` modifier from the class.
- If you cannot do that (for example, if the class is in a closed library), define a subclass that inherits from the abstract class and instantiate that class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an `abstract` class. What you can, though, is to use *inheritance* and use *implicit casting*

```
Derived derived = new Derived();
Abstract abstract = derived;
```

Through implicit casting you can treat a derived instance like a base-class instance.

From MSDN

```
The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified 
has a missing or incomplete implementation.
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a reference.

Comment: An abstract class can have a constructor! But you can not call it. A derived class, however, can call the constructor of its `base`.

Comment: Okay, agreed. But not calling them in the common sense.. You are talking about things like `Derived(int i) : base()`?

Comment: I'm saying that an abstract class can declare as many constructors as it wants. As you can not create an instance of an abstract class, you have no way of calling these, however, as you'll get an exception. Derived class can still also declare the constructor and call a constructor in the abstract base class using `base(...)`. See my answer for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in all previous answers: its impossible to instantiate abstract class.

Another important note: to instantiate instance by reflection you should use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but not constructor call.

```
object dynamicInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(yourType, yourArguments);
```

Object creation is a slightly more complicated process than simply calling constructor. It requires allocation necessary amount of memory and only then setting up object itself by calling constructor.